# How to filter display of Customizable Options in Product admin grid?

Tags: adminhtml, adminform, magento2.4.4, customizable-options

In the admin grid form of Products, I need certain Customizable Options to not be displayed even if they are assigned to a Product. These Customizable Options will be displayed in a separate section as they are managed differently.

Which core file needs to be overwritten in order to filter these Customizable Options in the admin form? Furthermore, **what is the procedure for discovering the file oneself**?

Here is a screenshot with the current display, and with some Customizable Options circled, indicating that I would like my module to filter them out on the backend (PHP):

[image]

Comment: Here are the few guides that are too good to do your task: https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-add-a-custom-filter-to-the-product-grid-in-magento-2.html
https://extensionsninjas.com/how-to-add-custom-filter-to-product-grid-in-magento-2-admin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! The `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php` file contains the necessary logic in the `modifyData()` method. There really is no way to find the file other than prior knowledge of Magento's architecture or (as in my case) a serendipity grep on the right regex.

To override the method of that class we configure `etc/adminhtml/di.etc`:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions">
    <plugin name="dotancohen_mod_configurableoptions_custom_options" type="Dotancohen\Mod\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

The corresponding `Plugin/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php` file must override the output of the `modifyData()` method, so it has an `afterModifyData()` method, whose second parameter is the output (return value) of the stock Magento `modifyData()` method:

```
<?php
namespace Dotancohen\Mod\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;

class CustomOptions {

    protected $_locator;

    public function __construct(LocatorInterface $locator)
    {
        $this->_locator = $locator;
    }


    /**
     * Modify output of modifyData() method
     */
    public function afterModifyData($subject, $result)
    {
        $prod_id = $this->_locator->getProduct()->getId();

        $opts = $result[$prod_id]['product']['options'];

        foreach ($opts as $k=>$v) {
            if ( optionMeetsSomeCriteria($v) ) {
                unset($opts[$k]);
            }
        }

        $result[$prod_id]['product']['options'] = array_values($opts);

        return $result;
    }

}
```

Note that the `$result[$prod_id]['product']['options']` array is repopulated by `array_values($opts)`, this is to reset the array keys to start from 0.

Now we go back to `etc/adminhtml/di.etc` and add the necessary Dependency Injection for the `LocatorInterface` object on the constructor:

```
<type name="Dotancohen\Mod\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="locator" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```